# Как правильно организовать получение ответа от поставщика услуг в СМЭВ 3 с помощью Java-клиента от НИИ Восход?

Tags: java, xml, soap

Настраиваю взаимодействие со СМЭВ-3 с помощью java-клиента от НИИ Восход.
Первоначальный запрос поставщику услуг SendRequestRequest проходит синхронную проверку сервиса и уходит на асинхронную. После этого я ставлю sleep 1 минуту и пробую отправить GetResponseRequest с помощью метода getResponse класса ru.voskhod.smev.message_exchange_service_clientMessageExchangeEndpoint. В ответ получаю пустой ответ

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:GetResponseResponse 
      xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/basic/1.1" 
      xmlns:ns2="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1" 
      xmlns:ns3="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/faults/1.1"/>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

При этом тело ответа отсутствует.

При вызове getStatus и getIncomingQueueStatistics - аналогично.

Документация что по клиенту, что от поставщиков, что официальная - основной момент уделяет отправке запроса SendRequestRequest, опуская дальнейшее взаимодействие. При этом, судя по форуму Криптопро, достаточно много людей пользуется СМЭВ-клиентом. Хотелось бы у тех, кто имеет опыт работы либо с клиентом, либо со СМЭВ 3 непосредственно, спросить как правильно получить результат обработки запроса?

Comment: Я уж подумал, что Вы пишите что-то для отечественного ПК "Восход" :D.

Comment: У нас схожая ситуация, техподдержка СМЭВ3 молчит. Ваша проблема разрешилась?

Comment: Ну, можно сказать что да. Поддержка ответила, что запрос пошёл все проверки, но чтобы получить ответ на тестовом контуре, надо отправить запрос к эмулятору. Для этого надо передать флаг test message. В клиенте это отдельный метод sendTestRequest. Я это раскопал, но пока не проверял, т.к. триал кончился на JCP, а он как то переставляется через одно место с поддержкой RuToken и OCF. То одно не цепляет, то другое. Пока времени не было заняться плотно.